# Compiler giving an unexpected error for casting a pointer as a struct in calloc()

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to create a dynamic array of pointers, each pointing to a diffrent structure, and the compiler gives me error: expected ')' before 'book'.I have tried struct * book, but it fails nevertheless. Why does it give this error and how to fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char book_name[32];
    char book_genre[32];
    char author[32];
    int page_count;
    float price;

}Sbook;
typedef struct
{
    char library_name[32];
    Sbook * bookp;
    int books_count;
}Slib;
void addexistingBooks(Slib library, Sbook book, int i);
int main()
{
    Slib library;
    Sbook book;
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter amount of books inside the library: ");
    scanf("%d", &(library.books_count));
    library.bookp = (Sbook * book)calloc(library.books_count,sizeof(struct book*));
    addexistingBooks(library, book, i);
    free(library.bookp);
    return 0;
}
void addexistingBooks(Slib library, Sbook book, int i)
{
    for(i=0;i<library.books_count;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the book: \n");
        fgets(library.bookp[i].book_name,32,stdin);
        printf("Enter the genre of the book: \n");
        fgets(library.bookp[i].book_genre,32,stdin);
        printf("Enter the author of the book: \n");
        fgets(library.bookp[i].author,32,stdin);
        printf("Enter the page count of the book: \n");
        scanf("%d", &(library.bookp[i].page_count));
        printf("Enter the price of the book: \n");
        scanf("%f", &(library.bookp[i].price));
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
```

Comment: `(Sbook * book)` should just be `(Sbook *)`. And `sizeof(struct book*)` should be `(sizeof Sbook)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: `addexistingBooks` doesn't appear to ever use its `book` argument, and the object that `main` passes to it is uninitialized?

Comment: @Barmar Well, it worked. Thanks

Comment: @Nate Elderidge. How so? It uses ```book``` to store data inside the elements of ```book```

Comment: Where in the code do you think it does that?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge During the ```for``` cycle

Comment: There is no reference to the parameter `book` on any of those lines.

Comment: @Nate Elderidge Well, you are actually right. I must have messed up the structure declaration and gettting data for the elements of the structure